# Simple way to check which cursor is in use at time of click?

Tags: javascript

I have an app which utilizes several different cursors (pointer, crosshair, etc.) depending on what the user is mousing over. Is there an easy reference to the cursor being used at the exact time of a click event?

Comment: Isn't testing which element was clicked on sufficient, if the cursor type "depend[s] on what the user is mousing over"?

Comment: Yes, I just wondered if there was a way to be clever and identify the region of the screen the cursor is in only by cursor type, something like document.getElementById("container").cursor

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using JQuery :

```
$('*').mouseenter(function(){

    /*Instead of "*" You can use a class/id selector if you wish to do this for a particular element*/

    /*You can replace mouseenter() with click() */

    var cursorType = $(this).css('cursor') ;

    /*you can do whatever you want here */

});
```

If you wish to change the cursor,

```
$('#selector').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```